# Jackson 3.0 unable to serialize object with @EmbededId

Tags: json, jackson

I am using resteasy jakson provide 3.0.17 and here is my object struicture.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class,
        property = "@id")
public class Product implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "id_seq", sequenceName = "id_seq")
    private Long productId;

    @Basic
    private String productName;

    @Basic
    private String type;

    @Basic
    private String productCode;

    @Basic
    private String outputName;

    @Basic
    private String creationMethod;

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "primaryKey.product")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<ProductDataElement> productDataElements = new HashSet<>();
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(schema = "product", name = "productdataelement")
// To cater to additional column in the mapping table
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "primaryKey.product", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "productId")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "primaryKey.dataElement", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "dataElementId")),
})
@Setter
public class ProductDataElement implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private ProductDataElementId primaryKey;

    @Basic
    private Long rowLimit;
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class ProductDataElementId implements Serializable {

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Product product;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private DataElement dataElement;

}
```

When I do a JPA query for a specific product, I get the nested structure on server side which contains `productDataElements` collection but when this data is send to browser by REST webservice call, I get collection with empty objects of `ProductDataElement` object. Any clue what can be the possible solution to get complete object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its resolved now..

I had to aadd

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class,
        property = "@id")
```

on ProductDataElementId and ProductDataElement to get it working.